# How narrow shell output?

Tags: shell

Emacs 25.1. 
I start `M-x shell`. And run some process that generate text to output. How can I filter this output?

Comment: The question risks being deleted because it is unclear, so far. Please define "*filter this output by narrow*". Specify just what you are looking for.

Comment: In console has 500 lines In some lines has text "hello". I want,  by narrow,to show only lines that contains text "hello"

Comment: @Alex: please answer Drew's question by editing your question rather than by adding a comment.  And while you're at it, please clarify why `M-x occur` or `M-x keep-lines` doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: Of cause I can use "M-x occur". And I oftet do this. But sometimes it's ore comfortable to use narrow